# How to use standard dict / list iterators with python gtk GenericTreeModel?

Tags: python, iterator, gtk

I have my own tree-isch data structure in memory and want to use the
gtk GenericTreeModel to display it. On some levels in my tree I have
dictionaries, on some other levels lists.
(I do not want the TreeStore, because then I have to link /
copy things around.  I want to operate on the original data.)

My idea is to use a dictionary / list iterator when implementing the
method `on_get_iter()`.  For the top level element the method looks
like (some code skipped):

```
def on_get_iter(self, path):
    return self.__my_data.get_dict().iteritems()
```

The method `on_iter_next()` is very simple:

```
def on_iter_next(self, rowref):
    try:
        return rowref.next()
    except StopIteration:
        return None
```

But then there is the need to get the data.  This is done with
`on_get_value()`.  I have no idea how to implement this:

```
def on_get_value(self, rowref, column):
    # What to write here?
```

The documentation says, that the value of the current row should be
returned here.  IMHO 'rowref.next()' does the wrong thing, because it
does not get the current but the next element.

IMHO there is no way to access the current element of an iterator (see
PEP 234).

Is there a way to use the GenericTreeModel with standard iterators
like dictionary or list iterators?

Update:
I found a workaround for this. Using the following iterator instead of the standard ones works for me; the constructor gets the standard dictionary / list iterator.

```
class GTMIterator:

    def __init__(self, iterator):
        self.__iterator = iterator
        self.__current = None
        self.next()

    def next(self):
        try:
            self.__current = self.__iterator.next()
        except StopIteration:
            return None
        return self.__current

    def current(self):
        return self.__current
```

But: IMHO this is only a workaround and not a 'clean' solution.

Answer (score 0):

One the way to do this would be as follows:

```
def on_get_iter(self, path):
  ...
  iterator = self.__my_data.get_dict().iteritems()
  data = iterator.next()
  return {'iterator': iterator, 'data': data}

def on_iter_next(self, rowref):
  try:
    iterator = rowref['iterator']
    next_data = iterator.next()
    return {'iterator': iterator, 'data': next_data}
  except StopIteration:
    return None

def on_get_value(self, rowref, column):
  key, value = rowref['data']
  return value[column]
```

The key here is that the `on_*` functions may return any user data object that
they wish. That object is automatically wrapped in a `gtk.TreeIter` using
`gtk.GenericTreeModel.create_tree_iter` and unwrapped again when calling
another `on_*` function using `gtk.GenericTreeModel.get_user_data`.

Hence, instead of returning just a python iterator, the key and value returned
by the last call to `next` method can be stored to access it in case it's
needed when calling to some other method.

Answer (score -1):

You need to implement [GtkTreeModel](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/3.2/GtkTreeModel.html) interface in your data-keeping object.
GtkTreeview use as model any GObject implementing that interface.

For futher references look at **[Overview of GtkTreeModel, GtkTreeView, and friends](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/3.2/TreeWidget.html)**

Comment: IMHO this does not answer the question.  I'm trying to implement the interface - the callbacks in python are called `on_get_iter()`, `on_iter_next()` or `on_get_value()`.  The question is about how to use a standard python container iterator as the iterator which is returned / used by a couple of those methods.